# Nexus 7K Xbar replacement

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

Does anyone know if the Xbar module (N7K-C7009-FAB-2) can cause any impact?

The replacement will take action during the maintenance window, but better safe than sorry.

Thanks in advance for answers

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Cisco Nexus 7009 switch has up to five fabric modules located on the front of the chassis. You can replace one of these fabric modules at a time while the switch is in full operation.

Official Cisco Replacement procedure:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/hw/nexus7000/installation/guide/n7k_hig_book/n7k_replacing.html#35412